# Sightly Implicit Objects

Tags: aem, sling, sightly, htl

I am trying to implement my own version of WCM's navigation component, whose [logic can be found here](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/Navigation.java), subbing my own logic instead:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;

public class Navigation extends WCMUsePojo{
    private Iterator<Page> items;

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        Page navRootPage = getCurrentPage().getAbsoluteParent(2);
        items = navRootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter());
    }
    public Iterator<Page> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

The HTL, [found here](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/navigation/v1/navigation), is identical.

I am able to iterate over the first level (at depth 4) of the navigation items. But the loop breaks in `item.html` at this line:
`<sly data-sly-test="${item.children.size > 0}" data-sly-call="${groupTemplate.group @ items = item.children}"></sly>`

Specifically, `item.children` does not appear to work even though these are implicit Sling objects. Any thoughts on why this is breaking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Navigation`](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/Navigation.java) model implemented in the Core WCM Components returns a list of [`NavigationItem`](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/NavigationItem.java) which expose their children via a `getChildren` method. That allows you to call it from HTL/Sightly with `item.children`. Since your use-object returns a list of WCM [`Page`](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/diff-previous/changes/com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page.html)s, you need to use the `listChildren` method. You can call it directly from HTL/Sightly using `item.listChildren`.

In general, for all objects, you can invoke a property getter using the standard JavaBeans conventions, see https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/use-api-java.html#Gettermethods. For a list of all objects available in AEM context in HTL/Sightly, see: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/global-objects.html