# HTL data-sly-test for listChildren

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

Is there a way to test if `listChildren` will return anything? Something along the line of: `<sly data-sly-test=${item.listChildren.size > 0} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a followup of [Sightly Implicit Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772366/sightly-implicit-objects), the `listChildren` method will return an `Iterator`. You can check it’s not empty by calling its `hasNext` method:

```
<sly data-sly-test=“${item.listChildren.hasNext}”>
```